Finding a second order interpolating polynomial going through two points exactly
Problem:
Given the following points:
$$ (x_0,y_0), (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), ... (x_n,y_n) $$
with the following limitations:
$$ x_0 = 0 $$
and
$$ x_0 < x_1 < x_2 .... < x_n  $$
We are also given a polynomial of the  form:
$$ P(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C $$
Find constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that:
$ P(x_0) = y_0 $, $P(x_n) = y_n $ and
the following expression is minimized:
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \left( P(x_i) - y_i \right) ^2 $$
Answer:
We have:
\begin{align*}
P(x_0) &= A(x_0)^2 + B(x_0 ) + C = y_0 \\
P(x_0) &= A(0)^2 + B(0 ) + C = y_0 \\
C &= y_0 \\
P(x_n) &= A(x_n)^2 + B(x_n ) + C = y_n \\
B(x_n ) &= y_n - A(x_n)^2  -  C \\
B &= \dfrac{ y_n - C }{x_n} - A(x_n) \\
B &= \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \\
\end{align*}
Now let
$$D = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \left( P(x_i) - y_i \right) ^2 $$
\begin{align*}
D &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \left( Ax_i^2 + Bx_i + C - y_i \right) ^2 \\
D &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
 \left(
  Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i + y_0 - y_i
 \right) ^2 \\
\end{align*}
Now we have $D$ as a function of $A$. We want to find a minimum value for $D$ as
a function  of $A$. Hence we differentiate.
$$ D = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
 2 \left(
 Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i + y_0 - y_i
 \right) 
 \left( x_i^2 -x_n x_i \right) 
$$
Now we set $D =  0$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
2 \left(
Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i + y_0 - y_i
\right) 
\left( x_i^2 -x_n x_i \right) &= 0 \\
%
\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
\left(
Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i + y_0 - y_i
\right) 
 &= 0 \\
 %
 \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
 \left(
 Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i  - y_i
 \right) 
 &= -(n-1)y_0 \\
 %
 \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}
    \left(
     Ax_i^2 + \left(  \dfrac{ y_n - y_0 }{x_n} - A(x_n) \right) x_i  
     \right) 
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}y_i - (n-1)y_0 \\
\end{align*}
Now, I need to solve for $A$. However, I do not know how to do that. I am hoping that somebody here can tell me how.

EDIT:
We know that a quadratic function is defined by 3 parameters, as the OP says $Ax^2 + Bx + C$. We want a convenient way to describe the set of quadratic functions which pass through two given points — this should have one degree of freedom. We know that a quadratic plus a line is still a quadratic. So we can write the solution as $P(x) = A(x-x_0)(x-x_n) +\ell(x)$ — a quadratic which has zeros at $x_0$ and $x_n$ plus a line, $\ell(x)$ passing through the two given points. Explicitly:
$$P(x) = A(x-x_0)(x-x_n) + (x-x_0)\left(\frac{y_n - y_0}{x_n-x_0}\right)+y_0$$
You can verify that $P(x_0) = y_0$ and $P(x_n) = y_n$, and that this is true for any value of A.
Now we will substitute the given value that $x_0 = 0$. We get that
$$P(x) = Ax(x-x_n) + x\left(\frac{y_n - y_0}{x_n}\right)+y_0 := Ax(x-x_n) + \ell(x).$$
Now we’ve described our one parameter space of solutions, and we want to select the best choice of A, so that $\sum_i (P(x_i) - y_i)^2$ is minimal. This is called least squares regression, and it is a standard technique — oceans of text have been written about this process.
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(P(x_i) - y_i)^2&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(Ax_i(x_i-x_n) -(y_i - \ell(x_i)))^2\\
&= \|A\vec{u} - \vec{v}\|^2
\end{align*}
Where $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are both $n-1$ dimensional vectors, the $i^{th}$ entry of  $\vec{u}$ is $x_i(x_i-x_n) $ and the $i^{th}$ entry of $\vec{v}$ is $y_i - \ell(x_i)$. Here $A\vec{u}$ represents a one dimensional line and $\vec{v}$ is a point, we will minimize the sum of squares if we pick $A$ to be the point on the line of scalar multiples of $\vec{u}$ which is closest to $\vec{v}$. This is the projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\vec{u}$. Thus $$A = \frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}}$$.

The initial reduction is clever but should perhaps be a little detailed.

its a quadratic with zeros at the two x coordinates plus a line which passes through the points.

Thanks, personnaly, I had understood it ; my remark was aimed at the asker for whom it may not be evident...

@LeeFisher I do not understand where the first line of your derivation comes from. I  cannot follow  any of it. Can you please put in a lot more detail? Also, if my partial solution is wrong, I  would like to know where I went  wrong,

First, trying to solve for B and C explicitly is not wrong per say, but it will prevent you from getting a simple description of the one parameter family you want to choose from. Also, it is very easy to make a mess of the algebra if you trying find the least square minima by using partial derivatives and not linear algebra.

I wrote: $Ax2+Bx+C$. You wrote: $A(x−x_0)(x−x_n)+(x−x_0)((y_n−y_0)/(x_nn−x0))+y_0$. Are they the same $A$? I do not see why it would be.

They must be the same $A$ because they are both the coefficient on $x^2$. The numbers $B$ and $C$ are functions of $A$ in some complicated way --but we do not need to figure out how they depend on $A$ explicitly in order to answer the question.
